# Collector never reaches the "end" event in discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am having a little issue with the collector's `time` property. Right now I have the following code:

```
const collector = message.createReactionCollector({
  time: timeInMilliseconds,
});
```

However, if I set a high value for `timeInMilliseconds` like 28800000 (8 hours) the `collector.on('end', callback)` is never triggered. Is this something related to the library or Node.js cleaning some stuff and preventing the collector to reach its end?

Comment: Because the collector needs to wait 8 hours before the 'end' event is triggered. I'm not sure what you're asking for.

Comment: I've re-read your question and I think I understand it now. discord.js doesn't seem to specify a max limit for the time a collector can be active, so maybe you can open an issue on their github. https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js

Comment: Consider showing an actual problem or what you've tried, have you tried waiting for 8 hours? If you have, this is a package bug, you can open an issue in the link posted by @Shockch4rge.

Answer (score 0):

for more information to use, you can use `package ms`,

```
const ms = require('ms')
const collector = message.createReactionCollector({
     time: ms('8h'), //You can use this as normal timer like s/m/h/d
});
```